# What is the normalization in the Noether normalization lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

As I understand it, the normalization of a domain $A$ is its integral closure in its field of fractions.

Why do we call the Noether normalization lemma by that name? What ring is being normalized?

Comment: This is, to some extend, explained in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472631/what-does-noethers-normalization-lemma-even-mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically Noether Normalization means that for any irreducible projective variety $X$ there is a finite map $\phi:X→ℙ^n$. In a sense, this helps to obtain a normalization of a variety, which is an attempt to make things nice by assuming  integrally closeness. Here are some links about this:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81420/noether-normalization-vs-normalization-of-varieties

[noether normalization theorem geometric meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320309/noether-normalization-theorem-geometric-meaning?rq=1)

[What is the meaning of normalization of varieties in complex geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085279/what-is-the-meaning-of-normalization-of-varieties-in-complex-geometry?noredirect=1&lq=1)